# Way to toggle counter without it being weird

Tags: javascript, jquery, reset

I have a reset button that does the job of removing rows, but I can't get the "Counter" JavaScript variable to reset without completely removing it until I hit reset again to toggle the visibility of counter.

I tried using `$("#counter").toggle("counter:reset");` but toggling doesn't seem to be the right thing to use. I've almost given up trying to find a way.

**jQuery:**

```
$("#resetBtn").click(function() {
  $('#myTable tr:not(:first)').remove(); 
  $("#counter").toggle("counter:reset"); 
});
```

codepen: http://codepen.io/BabinecJ/pen/dWMZNd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure what you need but this might help:

```
$("#resetBtn").click(function() {
  $('#myTable tr:not(:first)').remove(); 
  counter = 0;
  $("#counter").html(""); 
  $('[name="row_no" ]').val('');
});
```